# Check available heap memory in Android?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I get a `OutOfMemoryError` crash here:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
```

Is it a way to check wether enough memory available?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to not having a *single contiguous block* of free memory for the allocation. There is no means of testing that, short of try to allocate the memory and getting the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score -1):

put this code in android manifest file

```
  android:largeHeap="true";
```